# Add class when content has fully loaded angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I would like to add a class to the ng-view element when the content has fully loaded in angularjs, and remove it when the content is changed in the ng-view, so that I can add CSS animations. Is this possible?

I currently add animations using the ng-leave ng-enter classes which are added, but this doesn't wait until the content is fully loaded.

Thanks!

Comment: if i have understood your problem correctly, you can take a look at ng-animate directive. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

Comment: Can you clarify (with some minimum code) what you mean by "content is fully loaded"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using angular [1.2](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ngAnimate) or [1.3](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ngAnimate), you can add animation support to your ng-view using `ng-animate`.

Angular automatically add a class on different ng-view states.

From angular documentation

```
<style>
.slide.ng-enter { }        /* starting animations for enter */
.slide.ng-enter.ng-enter-active { } /* terminal animations for enter */
.slide.ng-leave { }        /* starting animations for leave */
.slide.ng-leave.ng-leave-active { } /* terminal animations for leave */
</style>
```

Just add angular-animate.js file after angular.js file, and add `ngAnimate` to your app dependencies to make use of these css classes.

#### Update

You can listen on [`$viewContentLoaded`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) event.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    $scope.myClass = 'view-loaded';
});
```

Comment: but this doesn't wait until content has loaded, as mentioned in OP